# How to repeat a task unlimited amount of times?

Tags: c#, repeat

I've just progressed up to building a semi advanced calculator in a Console App (.NET framework) and after the task of returning the result is done, I want to just repeat all of it over again as many times as the user wants to, how would I do that?

Code that I have:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Write("Enter a number: ");
            double num1 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.Write("Enter Operator (+, -, /, *) : ");
            string op = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.Write("Enter another number: ");
            double num2 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

            if(op == "+")
            {
                Console.WriteLine(num1 + num2);
            }
            else if(op == "-")
            {
                Console.WriteLine(num1 - num2);
            }
            else if (op == "/")
            {
                Console.WriteLine(num1 / num2);
            }
            else if (op == "*")
            {
                Console.WriteLine(num1 * num2);
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Wrap everything with `while(true) { /* your code */  }`

Comment: `while(true)` is bad advice for two reasons: 1) it will run forever and 2) doesn't accomplish what OP is asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap everything into a `while(true)`:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    while (true)
    {
        Console.Write("Enter a number: ");
        double num1 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.Write("Enter Operator (+, -, /, *) : ");
        string op = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.Write("Enter another number: ");
        double num2 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

        if(op == "+")
        {
            Console.WriteLine(num1 + num2);
        }
        else if(op == "-")
        {
            Console.WriteLine(num1 - num2);
        }
        else if (op == "/")
        {
            Console.WriteLine(num1 / num2);
        }
        else if (op == "*")
        {
            Console.WriteLine(num1 * num2);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

You should also probably include a way for the user to exit the application without having to close the window:

```
Console.WriteLine("Would you like to quit? [y/n]");
if (Console.ReadLine() == "y") return;
```

Comment: After the operation is done I have to press enter in order for the loop to activate, is there a way to make it instantly repeat it without having to press enter?

Comment: Just remove the `Console.ReadLine()` at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Use a loop? That should solve your problem. If you don't know what loops are you should research about them. They are a prime factor in all programming languages. Visit https://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_loops.htm for a tutorial on how to use them for your task.